# publish c structs

Tags: ros, c++, messages, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I'm searching for a way to publish my own c struct. In my code I use a struct like:

```
struct test {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  float d;
} ;
```

and I want a message that uses two integers and one "test". Of course I could use a message that uses five integers and one float to solve the problem but this is not a very well solution. I also tried [MessagesSerializationAndAdaptingTypes](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/MessagesSerializationAndAdaptingTypes) of the roswiki, but either I did something wrong or it does not help with this problem.

If there is already a post with this topic I'm sorry to ask this again, but I was not able to find it.

Best
ElTonno

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229469/publish-c-structs/) by [ElTonno](https://answers.ros.org/users/26320/eltonno/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-03-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-19**:\

> I also tried MessagesSerializationAndAdaptingTypes of the roswiki, but either I did something wrong [..]

It would help to know what exactly you tried, in order to avoid other posters suggesting the same things. Please include some example code-snippets showing what you tried (and any errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You always need a message definition to publish a message. This allows non-C++ clients to decode the message.

If you have a specific C/C++ type that you want to publish (`struct test`), you could define a matching message:

`test.msg`:

```
int32 a
int32 b
int32 c
float32 d
```

And define a message which uses that:

`combined.msg`

```
int32 e
int32 f
my_package/test g
```

You can then define a struct which contains a test:

```
struct combined_t {
  int e;
  int f;
  struct test g;
}
```

And then you can define a serializer for `combined_t`, which either uses the serializer for `struct test` or does everything inline, and then, finally, you'll be able to publish `combined_t` onto a topic with the `combined.msg` type.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3